# Synchronization of branch with master and push to Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Perhaps this is trivial situation however for some reason (actually i'm not advanced in Git ) I have got stuck.

I'm working on project with multiple repositories managed by "repo" and trying to make branch synchronized with master so I can push it to gerrit.

I have made changes only in one repository but want to synchronize with master other repositories (repositories without code changes in branch).

When I ran the following commands I synchronized the branch with master without conflicts (because no changes were made in branch):
`git checkout master && git pull && git checkout MY-BRANCH && git merge master`

Console output:

```
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'master'
Already up to date.
Branch 'MY-BRANCH' set up to track remote branch 'MY-BRANCH' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'MY-BRANCH'
Already up to date.
Updating 0b6aed8..b048505
Fast-forward
 package.json | 4 ++--
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

It shows that package.json was changed (synchronized with master).

So now, I just need to commit it to gerrit and when I use the command:
`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/MY-BRANCH/topicname`

the output is the following:

```
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://gerrit.company.com:12345/path/to/repository
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/MY-BRANCH/topicname (no new changes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://username@gerrit.company.com:12345/path/to/repository'
```

the command `git status` shows the following:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/MY-BRANCH' by 15 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Probably I don't understand something doing synchronization of branch with master and pushing it to remote.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the workaround. Not sure this is correct way but it works for me.

It is possible to make empty commit `git commit --allow-empty -m "Synchronization with master"` after which push is possible. With this approach I got commit in gerrit where there are no code changes however the branch is synchronized with master.